# jQuery script #url change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a **[jQuery script](http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery)** to scroll though pages (divs). If you type # + item(number) in the url, you'll get the desired page (div). However when navigating through the menu, the url, doesn't change accordingly.

How do I get the url, to change accordingly when I navigate the script though the menu?

Also, is there a way for me to remove "item" from the url (#item02), and only leave the numbers?
Or even better, have custom #names for each page (div)?

```
<script>
function resizePanel(){
    width = $(window).width(); 
    height = $(window).height();
    mask_width = width*$(".item").length; 

    $("#debug").html(); 
    $(".wrapper, .item").css({}); 
    $(".mask").css({});
    $(".wrapper").scrollTo($("a.selected").attr("href"),0)}

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.panel").click(function(){
            $("a.panel").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            current = $(this);
            $(".wrapper").scrollTo($(this).attr("href"),800);
            return false;
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){resizePanel()})
    })
</script>
```

Comment: As you are bypassing the normal bookmark-link behaviour, You need to use something like History.js to manage the browser history and hash links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your clickhandler you can add a hash to your location like that:

```
$("a[href=#item4]").unbind().click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // scroll to desired container
  $(".wrapper").scrollTo($(this).attr("href"),800, function(){
      // update location
      var url = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname,     
      hash = '#item4';   
      window.location.href = url + hash; 
  });
});
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. `<script>
$("#item4").click(function(){
    var url = window.top.location.origin + window.top.location.pathname,
    hash = '#/contact';
 window.location.href = url + hash;
});
</script>`

Comment: Yes because your selector is wrong. Try this:  `$("a[href=#item4]").click(function(){     var url = window.top.location.origin + window.top.location.pathname,     hash = '#/contact';  window.location.href = url + hash; });`

Comment: It works now. However it creates another problem. **[Take a look.](http://pad.ample.pw/ucc/)** The animation wont work.

Comment: Thanks for trying. However, same problem still persists. **[URL](http://pad.ample.pw/ucc/)**

Comment: Unbind added...Still nothing. :(

Comment: I took a closer look and updated the answer. The location.href needs to be updated when the animation is finished. Otherwise it overwrites your animation and jumps directly to the container.

Comment: Did you give it a try?